# Does anyone know what happened with tkinter scrollbars(sliders)? Many options do not work

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

So I've been using tkinter for a long time, but never used sliders. Decided to make an image editing app, i need sliders to adjust the radius of a blurring effect. Google says that there are several useful options, but when i try to integrate those options i get an error, checked the **init** file and it says the following:

> "Valid resource names: activebackground, activerelief, background,
>   bd, bg, borderwidth, command, cursor, elementborderwidth,
>   highlightbackground, highlightcolor, highlightthickness, jump, orient,
>   relief, repeatdelay, repeatinterval, takefocus, troughcolor, width."

I need some other options that seem to have been working in the past, because all the forums in the internet use them.

Options that used to be there: from_, to, length, variable

```py
def blurr():
    global slidervar
    frm = Frame(root, bg='gray')
    frm.place(x=10, y=520, width=980, height=70)
    slider = Scrollbar(frm, orient = HORIZONTAL, from_=0, to = 100, variable = slidervar)
    # slider.config(length =100)
    slider.pack()
```

The error:

> [_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-from"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbYSh.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing has changed with the Scrollbar widget in a couple of decades. Scrollbars have never had a `from_` or `to` option. Perhaps you are thinking of the Scale widget which has always had a `from_` and `to` option.

Comment: I feel really stupid, thank you man and i apologise for my stupid question